# Limit definition of a sequence question

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, definition

I'm trying to use the limit definition of a sequence to prove that the limit as $ n \rightarrow \infty$ of $\frac{1}{10^n}$ is equal to $0$. It is evident to see that this limit approaches 0,this is my work thus far.. not sure how I am allowed to rearrange for $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$ to complete the proof appropriately. I feel like it's something extremely basic.

If $\frac{1}{10^n} \rightarrow 0$, then 
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 , \exists N \in \mathbb{Z}$$
such that 
$ \lvert X_n - L \rvert < \epsilon$ whenever $ n \geq N$.
Thus we let $ \epsilon > 0$, then 
$$ \lvert X_n - L \rvert = \lvert \frac{1}{10^n} - 0 \rvert$$
$$ \lvert X_n - L \rvert = \lvert \frac{1}{10^n}  \rvert$$\
$$ \rightarrow 1/10^n < \epsilon$$

Comment: So what value of $N$ would make the inequality $1/10^n <\epsilon$ work for $n> N$? Note that your $N$ should be some expression containing $\epsilon$.

Comment: your title is really vague and too broad. Please reflect what your Q is actually asking. This is not a general question about limits its a very specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that we need $\frac1{10^n}<\epsilon$ to make it work. To see when this can happen, note that we can equivalently write this as $10^{-n}<\epsilon.$ If you happen to know that the logarithm (base $10$) is an increasing function, then this is equivalent to $$-n<\log\epsilon,$$ which is in turn equivalent to $$n>-\log\epsilon.$$ Now use the Archimedean Property.

(Please let me know if I used any unfamiliar ideas, here.)

Perhaps a more elementary way, if you're familiar with induction, is to show that $n<10^n$ for all positive integers $n,$ so that $$\frac1{10^n}<\frac1n$$ for all such $n.$ Then all you have to do is make sure that $n>\frac1\epsilon$ and you're home free.

Comment: Ahh the induction method makes sense, never heard of the Archimedean Property yet but thank you!!

Comment: For future reference, the Archimedean Property (of the reals) says that, given any fixed real number $x,$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that $N>x.$ So, letting $N$ be a positive integer greater than $-\log\epsilon,$ we see that $\frac1{10^n}<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N,$ from which the desired conclusion follows. Glad the induction made sense to you!

Comment: Extremely helpful, and I noted that for future reference!

Comment: Very good and clear explanation. +1

Answer (score 0):

We can show for $0 <c <1$ then $ c^n \to 0$. Write $ c=\frac {1}{1+p} $ for $ p> 0$. Then, $|c^n|=|\frac {1}{(1+p)^n}|<|\frac {1}{1+np}|$ by Bernoulli and it is easy to see that the latter tends to zero.